# COMODO AntiVirus for Linux cannot be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bits

Tags: 64-bit, antivirus

The last version of COMODO AntiVirus for Linux, 64 bits version, cannot be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64 bits.

However, the 32 bits version of the program can be installed into a 64 bits OS, but... Is this a good idea?

Please, I need some help here, because it is intended to protect an "always connected" PC, with Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS (and the idea is to be "always" protected, a thing which we cannot get with CLAMAV).

Comment: Please provide us with more information such as what exactly you have tried and what has gone wrong as well as any error messages you were provided with.

Comment: You certainly are entitled to install AV in linux, but it's not normally a required step like it is on a windows machine.  I'm not recommending against it, however, I also don't want you to feel vulnerable without it.  There is plenty of reading (google-fu) on the subject whether or not it's needed.  In fact, Ubuntu takes a 'probably not needed' public stance. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-antivirus.html

Comment: If you use 64 bits Ubuntu, when you try to install COMODO 64 bits, you get the infamous error message: "not all dependences can be satisfied for this package". If you use 64 bits Ubuntu and you try to install COMODO 32 bits, then you can do it. But, my question is if to install a 32 bits antivirus into a 64 bits OS is a good idea. Linux isn't full free for hacker attacks (virus or any other trick). Linux needs antivirus and firewall software. Nobody is safe into the Internet jungle. So...

Comment: Why would it be bad?  64 bit can run 32 but with the right libraries.  Obviously there are limitations to running 32 bit, but it isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks for your data. I'll install the 32 bits version. I'll trust in COMODO.

Comment: Problems!!! I installed COMODO 32 bits into Ubuntu 64 bits, but it doesn't run. The system told me that "the /opt/COMODO/ directory doesn't exist". However, the directory is here, very clear. But it doesn't run.

Comment: Late. Apparently there were a few changes in the kernel that prevents COMODO from starting its real-time shield. We have to wait for COMODO to update their app.

Answer (score 2):

I found thisn helped install comodo x64 bit version, you have to manually install a dependency first then just download from commodo site the version x64.

libssl0.9.8 is no longer available in ubuntu 16.04 repositories. You can download and install manually the deb file from this link if you want libssl0.9.8 (clic on the link "security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" when you reach that page).

the dependency: [Dependency install](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libssl0.9.8/download)

after install, you need this:

sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh

space bar throught the entire licence, then agree.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo dpkg -i cav-linux_x64.deb`
2. `sudo /opt/COMODO/post_setup.sh`
3. `sudo /opt/COMODO/cav`
4. the comodo will run
5. run diagnotics
6. update Virus Database

Comment: The process you describe fails after the step 2. There is a lot of errors at that point. However, the main kernel of the software is running, but not with the real time routine. On old Ubuntu versions, it run (we had to do the same history you are telling). Maybe something is missing at 16.04 LTS version.

Comment: yes,i agree something is missing at the new version..i install it with this steps and it succeed..i don't know how it worked but i install it ..